# rails nested form not submitting parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following view

```
   <%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
    <%# @event.eventdistances.in_groups_of(6, false) do |eventdistances| %>
    <div class='row'>
      <% @event.eventdistances.each do |ed| %>
        <div class='small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns'>
          <%= fields_for "eventdistances[]", ed do |ff| %>
            <%= ff.check_box :active %> <%= ed.struttura.nome %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%# end %>
```

generates a request which has the id of the parent object, but is not invoking it in the params hash.

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"l5xHBsUuL5uM/ip2P0jWLxMi46zhVOxo1vyei9xdLPDFxL3IHmVBAhz/vfu1esJjIBZbElG2pefp+zbAC1vivQ==", "eventdistances"=>{"1"=>{"active"=>"0"}}, "commit"=>"Confirm changes", "id"=>"5"}
```

Naturally, strong params complains as the param is missing in

```
params.require(:event).permit(*permitted)
```

where is this form lacking?

Comment: input name in html source need to be like this `event[evendistances][0][active]`. I'm not sure, but maybe need to change this line `= fields_for "eventdistances[]"` for example, like this `= fields_for "event[eventdistances][]"` . it's probably wrong setup for `fields_for` but idea it's to make your input name to be `event[nested][index][column]`

Comment: not fully, because strong params is now tripping up on `eventdistances` as being unpermitted, although I have defined it.  Interestingly enough, the same syntaxtic structure works in another part of the app...

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%= f.fields_for :eventdistances do |ff| %>
```

was the proper syntax, while ensuring that strong params included `id`

```
eventdistances_attributes: [:id,  ... ]
```